# Where do I find my EC2 private key?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I'm trying to set up the EC2 API tools and I'm stuck because I cannot figure out where I can obtain the file pointed to by the EC2_PRIVATE_KEY environment variable (I believe I have the EC2_CERT).

Of the multitude of different access credentials visible in the EC2 user interface, which one do I need to make the command line tools work?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Ok, turns out that I need to generate a new X.509 certificate, and then I'll be able to download both the EC2_PRIVATE_KEY and the EC2_CERT files.

This link proved useful: http://paulstamatiou.com/how-to-getting-started-with-amazon-ec2

Comment: Hey - thanks so much for answering your own question! It's really helpful for others when we arrive here from Google. :) PW

Comment: I can't find where "AWS Access Identifiers page" is!

Comment: Same problem and solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369547/amazon-ec2-lost-private-key-how-to-get-access-to-the-server

Answer (score 7):

The private key is only downloadable at the moment you create the certificate.

Comment: Very helpful.  I can only have two access keys so I deleted one, created another and then downloaded the credentials as a CSV.  Worked great!  Thanks!

Comment: How do I download the private key from Amazon AWS?

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html

> Note
>
> Amazon EC2 doesn't keep a copy of your private key; therefore, if you
>   lose a private key, there is no way to recover it. If you lose the
>   private key for an instance store-backed instance, you can't access
>   the instance; you should terminate the instance and launch another
>   instance using a new key pair. If you lose the private key for an
>   EBS-backed Linux instance, you can regain access to your instance. For
>   more information, see Connecting to Your Linux Instance if You Lose
>   Your Private Key.

And here are steps for recovery (by generating a new key pairs):

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=102074