# Where is the EC2 Ubuntu RSA Certificate and private key located for use with SFTP?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I've installed `vsftpd` on an Ubuntu EC2 instance but I'm not sure where the certificate files are to enter into `vsftpd`. The documentation says I need to add the following lines:

```
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
```

However, when I try and login using the normal `ec2-keypair.pem` file I get the message `invalid privatekey`

Comment: Do you mean FTPS?  SFTP runs over SSH, and is unrelated to FTP.

Comment: Yes, I want to use FTPS but don't I need to add the RSA key details to vsftpd.conf? I don't know where they're actually located on a standard Ubuntu EC2 instance.

Comment: Figure out what exactly you want then revise your question... VSFTP has nothing to do with the ec2-keypair.pem file, but can be used for SFTP as Steve mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

You should ideally generate a new keypair.  There's lots of stuff via google about how to do that with openssl.  If you want to try using the ec2 keypair, which would mean placing your ec2 private key on this server (which I don't recommend for security reasons) you could try placing the key in the file ~ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys as the public key, and the ec2 private key you have on your own machine as the private key.

Again, not recommended, since this would mean that someone who had sufficient access to this server could then get the private key, and log into any of the ec2 instances you had brought up using this keypair.

Comment: agreed, not recommended, because private key is only created for you when the EC2 instance is created which you must download, and after which Amazon will delete it.   Amazon only keep the public key.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/185868/where-do-i-find-my-ec2-private-key/796809#796809